# How do I create accessors for ActiveRecord models from an array of symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, metaprogramming, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following so far

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def name=(s)
    super s.encrypt
  end
  def name
    (super || '').decrypt
  end
```

I would like to replace it and do something like

```
@@encrypted_fields = [:name, :phone, :address1, ...]
def self.initialize
  @@encrypted_fields.each do |s|
    setter = (s.to_s+'=')(value) -> do
      super value.encrypt
    end
    getter = (s.to_s) -> do
      (super || '').decrypt
    end
    User.send(:include, setter)
    User.send(:include, getter)
  end
end
```

I can't do this for all the records, like email, of course (how will they log in?), and some fields aren't important enough to bother.

I tried

```
  @@encrypted_fields = [:name, :phone, :address1]
  @@encrypted_fields.each do |m|
    setter = (m.to_s+'=').to_sym
    getter = m
    define_method(setter) do |v|
      super v.encrypt
    end
    define_method(getter) do
      (super || '').decrypt
    end
  end
```

based on [Use def_method inside ActiveRecord model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581071/use-def-method-inside-activerecord-model)

but it gave

> implicit argument passing of super from method defined by define_method() is not supported. Specify all arguments explicitly. 
>   `(super || '').decrypt`

Comment: Not a duplicate! The method has no arguments!

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13544356/148844. `super()` worked.